# How remove the newest content from Drupal View, when exposed filter is activated?

Tags: php, drupal, view, drupal-7

I have trouble figuring out how to make Drupal 7 view do what I want. I have experience with Drupal, but not much in php coding itself.

#### What I use:

```
 Druapl 7, View 3, Entity, Date
```

#### What I did:

I created two views. One shows the newest content type, the other all the rest.
On the second content type you have an exposed filter where you can filter out content based on their category. (Categories are created with entity module)

**1 view settings:**

- Filter criteria: content type
- Sort Criteria: start date(desc)(datemodule)
- Pager: Display a specified number of items: 1 item.

**2 view settings:**

- Filter criteria: content type, chose category(exposed)
- Sort Criteria: start date (desc)(date module)
- Pager: Display all items | all items, skip 1

### The problem:

1 view works as I want.
2 view works on the first load when exposed filter is set to “any”. The newest content type is not showed.
Now, if I use the exposed filter, and select a category, every 1 content from the result is left out.

### What I want:

What I want is that the “2 view" wouldn't show the newest (based on date module field) content type (the content type that is shown on “1 view”).

I understand that's how pager is working and there is no issue, so I assume the solution to my problem is a combination of Contextual filter and php code. Where I would tell to view to exclude the newest content type only.

Not fully sure how to do that.
Can't add a fixed node nid either as it is constantly changing. And I don't want to create a Boolean field where user needs to check it if it is the newest, and deselect if it is not.

I appreciate every hint or advice you are willing to share to fix the problem.

### Additional info:

I'm using two separate views and they have their own pages.

how "2 view" should look like

Newest content type (exclude): 
Content A: category A

what shows up:

- Content B: category A,
- Content C: category A,
- Content D: category B,
- Content E: category B.

If I set filter: Category A
it shows:

- Content B: category A,
- Content C: category A,

If I set filter: Category B
it shows:

- Content D: category B,
- Content E: category B.

with pager offset 1, I can not do it, as it will remove the newest category B content, if I set the filter to "Category B".
I want the 2 view do not show overall(doesn't mather its category) the newest content, what would be in the example: "Content A: category A"

Comment: Are you using 1 view with 2 displays or 2 seperate views and are they both used on 1 page or do they have their own page?

Comment: Hei BaikHo. thank you, didn't specify that. I'm using two separate views, and they have their own pages. added as well under additional info.

Comment: Just to make sure, once you select a category from your exposed filter it's empty you say. Are their at least 2 nodes for each of your category type? If there's only 1 it would skip 1 leaving your view with no results.

Comment: yes, thats the dilemma I'm having :). 
After I chose a category from exposed filters it also removes the first entry under the category.
I'm aware thats how the pager works and there is no error.

What I want is that only the newest content type of overall wouldn't be showed in the Second view. And If I chose a category under the filter, than unless it is the newest content type of overall(between all the categories) it would show.

Comment: added under additional info extra info how I want the view to work. Hope I'm more understandable with that :)

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is a little code.  Unset that pager offset so all the data gets through.  Using a hook_views_pre_render you can check the filter values.  If the filter is empty, unset the first result of the view.  If the filter has a value, leave the results alone.
https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7

```
if( empty($view->exposed_raw_input['my_input']['filter_field'])) {
  array_shift($view->result);
}
```

If you do not specify your view name in your hook, this will apply to all views on your site.  Just a little caution.